# Drawbacks of a Sudo Strategy Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working on a project where I need to call many different services and wanted to abstract out as much of the common logic as I can. The kicker is that I also want to return custom objects instead of something such as json. As I designed a way of doing this, I arrived at a paradigm that reminds me of a Strategy Pattern, but I don't quite think it fits. I'm wondering if there are any design flaws or dangers in how I've done this.

Basically I've created an abstract class (`ServiceCall`) that holds the common logic for calling a service (have an internet client and get a json response from the desired service). This is all done with the public method `call(Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> headers)`. The abstract class also defines two abstrach methods: `createCustomDTO(Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> headers)` and `parseResponseToObject(String json)`. I'll explain the purpose of these in just a second.

Each call to a different service will be created with a class that extends `ServiceCall` and creates an implementation of the abstract methods. `createCustomDTO` will create a custom object that contains all the information needed to call the service (url, and headers). `parseResponseToObject` will take a json response and turn it into the java object I want to use later in my code.

Here is a simple implementation of what I did

**ServiceCall**

```
public abstract class ServiceCall {

    protected abstract Object parseResponseToObject(String json);

    protected abstract CustomServiceDTO createDTO(Map<String, String> keys,
        Map<String, String> headers);

    public Object call(Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> headers) {

        // create and configure a CustomServiceDTO to call services with
        CustomServiceDTO dto = createDTO(params, headers);

        try {
            // make the service request
            String json = getServiceResponse(dto);
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new CustomServiceError(e);
        }

        // parse the response into the desired java object
        Object response = parseResponseToObject(json);
        return response;
    }

    private String getServiceResponse(CustomServiceDTO dto) {
        // use common logic to call the service using the information provided
        // by the dto

        String dummyResponse = "{\"prop\":\"value\"}";
        return dummyResponse;
    }
}
```

**SampleImplementation**

```
    public class AddressCall extends ServiceCall {

    @Override
    protected Object parseResponseToObject(String json) {
        return new Address(json);
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomServiceDTO createDTO(Map<String, String> keys, 
        Map<String, String> headers) {
        CustomServiceDTO dto = new CustomServiceDTO();
        dto.setUrl("www.getMyDummyAddress.com/" + keys.get(0) + "=" + keys.get(1));
        dto.setHeaders(headers);
        return dto;
    }
}
```

The main drawback I see to this is that never directly calling `createCustomDTO` and `parseResponseToObject` is a little strange.

The main advantage for me is the ease of use and having my responses returned as java objects.

What I really want to know is are there any other concerns or drawbacks to this paradigm? It's very nice in the code, but I admit it seems a bit different from how java is normally used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not different from how Java is normally used, this is called a [Template Method](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-template-method) design pattern.

It's pretty common, except for the use of Object, which is better replaced by a generic type.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I hadn't heard of the Template Method yet. The link was also very helpful as it both explained the strengths of it and linked out to a blog post criticizing the pattern. - http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-template/